# Python, JavaScript, PHP, HTML: Unbeatable Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, tic-tac-toe

At first, I created an unbeatable Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python. However, I wanted a better interface, so I used a PHP backend that runs the script and simple JavaScript that sends user commands to the script.

**index.html**: (excuse stupid class names)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='jquery.js'></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='styling.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src='code/ttt-realhard.js'></script>
  <title> Tic-Tac-Toe Unbeatable </title>
  <style>
  table {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: bold 36px sans-serif;
}
p,
h1,
td,
th {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
table,
td,
th {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
    td, th {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    #board tr td:hover {
        background: #e4e4e4;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .ab_c {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    td#c0,
    td#c1,
    td#c2,
    td#c3,
    td#c4,
    td#c5 {
        border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
    }
    td#c0,
    td#c1,
    td#c3,
    td#c4,
    td#c6,
    td#c7 {
        border-right: 3px solid grey;
    }
    .lolyoucantbeatme {
        color: grey;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 4em;
    }
    .lolyoureallywontbutyoucantry {
        color: grey;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- v1.0 unbeatable-->
  <!-- by joseph -->
  <div id='youwontbeatme'>
    <h1 class='lolyoucantbeatme ab_c' style='top:2%'> Tic Tac Toe </h1>
    <p class='lolyoureallywontbutyoucantry ab_c' style='top:10%'> Try to beat me! </p>
  </div>
  <img src='spinner2.gif' id='spinner' width='150' height='150' style='display:none;' class='ab_c'>
  <table id='board' class='ab_c' style='top:55%'>
    <tr>
      <td id='c0' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td><td id='c1' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td><td id='c2' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='c3' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td><td id='c4' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td><td id='c5' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='c6' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td><td id='c7' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td><td id='c8' onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id='lawl'class="ab_c" style="left: 90%;white-space: nowrap;display: none;"><p id='status'></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ttt-realhard.js**:

```
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
ttt = {
  "ticclick": function(cell) {
    if ($(cell).html() == '' && !ttt.system.laptopresponse) { $(cell).html('X'); ttt.system.lock();ttt.system.freecode();ttt.system.help(); }
    // TODO: Wait for computer move.
  },
  "realz": [
    '#c0','#c1','#c2',
    '#c3','#c4','#c5',
    '#c6','#c7','#c8'
  ],
}
ttt['system'] = {
  "freecode": function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ttt.realz.length; i++) {
      var ab = $(ttt.realz[i]);
      if (ab.html() == "X") {
        ab.css('background-color', '#b3b3ff');
      } else if (ab.html() == 'O') {
        ab.css('background-color', '#ffcccc');
      }
    }
  },
  "coolstatus": function(logic, step) {
    if (!logic) return; // stupid hack, too lazy to figure out why sometimes logic is not passed.
    var step = step || 0;
    if (step > logic.length) {$('#lawl').hide();return;}
    $('#lawl').show().html(logic[step]);
    step++;
    setTimeout(function() { ttt.system.coolstatus(logic, step); }, 50)
  },
  "boardencode": function(board) {
    /* Encodes a board to a format that is easily transferred. */
    var buffer = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      buffer += (board[i] == '' ? '-' : board[i]); // ternary operators are cool
    }
    return buffer;
  },
  "laptopresponse": false,
  "lock": function() {
    console.log('locked');
    $('#spinner').show();
    $('#youwontbeatme').hide();
    ttt.system.laptopresponse = true;
  },
  "unlock": function() {
    console.log('unlocked');
    $('#spinner').hide();
    $('#youwontbeatme').show();
    ttt.system.laptopresponse = false;
  },
  "isWaitingForLaptop": function() {
    return ttt.system.laptopresponse;
  },
  "parseServerResponse": function(dat) {
    // Parse board.
    ab = JSON.parse(dat);
    ttt.system.coolstatus(ab.Board.Logic);
    for (var i = 0; i < ab.Board.DBoard.length; i++) {
      $("#c" + i.toString()).html(null == ab.Board.DBoard[i] ? "" : ab.Board.DBoard[i]);
    }
    // Now, check for a winner.
    ttt.system.freecode();
    if (ab.Board.Complete) {
      // Someone won...
      // Check for a tie, perhaps?
      if (!ab.Board.Winner) {
        // Tie!
        console.log('Tie.');
        $('#spinner').css('width', '200px').css('height','200px');
        $('#youwontbeatme').show().html("<h1 class='lolyoucantbeatme ab_c' style='top:2%'> TIE! </h1>");
        $('.lolyoucantbeatme').css('color', 'orange');
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace("index.html")},5e3);
        //$('#lawl').show().html('<a href="easy/"> Play the easy version instead? </a>');
        return 0;
      } else if (ab.Board.Winner == 'O') {
        console.log('Computer win.');
        $('#youwontbeatme').show();
        $('#youwontbeatme').html("<h1 class='lolyoucantbeatme ab_c' style='top:2%'> I won. </h1>");
        $('.lolyoucantbeatme').css('color', 'red');
        $('#c'+ab.Board.WinningCombo[0].toString()).css('font-weight','bold').css('color','red');
        $('#c'+ab.Board.WinningCombo[1].toString()).css('font-weight','bold').css('color','red');
        $('#c'+ab.Board.WinningCombo[2].toString()).css('font-weight','bold').css('color','red');
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace("index.html")},5e3);
        //$('#lawl').show().html('<a href="easy/"> Play the easy version instead? </a>');
        return 0;
      }
    }
    // No one won. Unlock board.
    console.log('unlocking board cuz no one won');
    ttt.system.unlock();
  },
  "help": function() {
    console.log('Sending to server: ' + ttt.system.boardencode(ttt.system.collect()))
    // Help!
    pre='inhumane';
    jQuery.get("code/server.php?mode="+pre+"&data=" + ttt.system.boardencode(ttt.system.collect()), ttt.system.parseServerResponse);
  },
  "collect": function() {
    var buffer = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ttt.realz.length; i++) {
      buffer[i] = $(ttt.realz[i]).html();
    }
    return buffer;
  }
}
var goFirst = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
if (goFirst == 1) {
  $(document).ready(ttt.system.help);
}
```

**server.php**:

```
<?php
  isset($_GET['mode']) || die('ERR_NOMODE');
  isset($_GET['data']) || die('ERR_NODATA');
  $MODE      = $_GET['mode'];
  $BOARDDATA = $_GET['data'];
  $INVOKE    '/Users/joe/Desktop/ScienceFair/ttt/unbeatable_raw.py %s';
  $RESULT    = exec(sprintf($INVOKE, $BOARDDATA));
  // echo('Invoked '. sprintf($INVOKE, $BOARDDATA));
  echo($RESULT);
?>
```

**The guts (Python script):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random, os, sys, json

class Tic(object):
    lastwincombo = []
    logic = []
    winning_combos = (
        [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6])

    winners = ('X-win', 'Draw', 'O-win')

    def __init__(self, squares=[]):
        if len(squares) == 0:
            self.squares = [None for i in range(9)]
        else:
            self.squares = squares

    def available_moves(self):
        return [k for k, v in enumerate(self.squares) if v is None]

    def available_combos(self, player):
        return self.available_moves() + self.get_squares(player)

    def complete(self):
        if None not in [v for v in self.squares]:
            return True
        if self.winner() != None:
            return True
        return False

    def X_won(self):
        return self.winner() == 'X'

    def O_won(self):
        return self.winner() == 'O'

    def tied(self):
        return self.complete() == True and self.winner() is None

    def winner(self, lastcheck = False):
        for player in ('X', 'O'):
            positions = self.get_squares(player)
            for iterator, combo in enumerate(self.winning_combos):
                win = True
                for pos in combo:
                    if pos not in positions:
                        win = False
                if win:
                    self.lastwincombo = combo
                    return player
        return None

    def get_squares(self, player):
        return [k for k, v in enumerate(self.squares) if v == player]

    def make_move(self, position, player):
        self.squares[position] = player

    def alphabeta(self, node, player, alpha, beta):
        if node.complete():
            if node.X_won():
                return -1
            elif node.tied():
                return 0
            elif node.O_won():
                return 1
        for move in node.available_moves():
            node.make_move(move, player)
            val = self.alphabeta(node, get_enemy(player), alpha, beta)
            node.make_move(move, None)
            if player == 'O':
                if val > alpha:
                    alpha = val
                if alpha >= beta:
                    return beta
            else:
                if val < beta:
                    beta = val
                if beta <= alpha:
                    return alpha
        if player == 'O':
            return alpha
        else:
            return beta


def determine(board, player):
    a = -2
    choices = []
    if len(board.available_moves()) == 9:
        return 4
    for move in board.available_moves():
        board.make_move(move, player)
        val = board.alphabeta(board, get_enemy(player), -2, 2)
        board.make_move(move, None)
        board.logic.append("move:{} and it causes:{}; ".format(move,board.winners[val + 1]))
        if val > a:
            a = val
            choices = [move]
        elif val == a:
            choices.append(move)
    return random.choice(choices)


def get_enemy(player):
    if player == 'X':
        return 'O'
    return 'X'
a = sys.argv[1]
a=str.upper(a)
a=list(a)
for i,v in enumerate(a):
    if v == '-':
        a[i] = None
if __name__ == "__main__":
    board = Tic(a)
    dat = {"Board": {"Complete": True, "NextMove": 0, "Winner": None, "WinningCombo": [], "Logic": None, "DBoard": []}}
    #board.show()
    player = 'X'
    if board.complete():
        dat['Board']['Winner'] = board.winner()
        dat['Board']['WinningCombo'] = board.lastwincombo;
        dat['Board']['DBoard'] = board.squares
        print(json.dumps(dat))
        sys.exit()
    player = get_enemy(player)
    computer_move = determine(board, player)
    board.make_move(computer_move, 'O')
    if board.complete():
        dat['Board']['Winner'] = board.winner()
        dat['Board']['WinningCombo'] = board.lastwincombo;
        dat['Board']['DBoard'] = board.squares
        print(json.dumps(dat))
        sys.exit()
    dat['Board']['Logic']    = board.logic
    dat['Board']['DBoard'] = board.squares
    dat['Board']['Complete'] = False
    dat['Board']['NextMove'] = computer_move
    print(json.dumps(dat))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As JosephtheDreamer has left the Python to someone else, I'll take up the challenge.

It's a small thing, but the styling for the definition of `winning_combos` doesn't seem right to me.  We can see the start of the definition and what is inside, but the close parenthesis is hidden at the end of one of the lines.  I prefer to put it on its own line:

```
winning_combos = (
    [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6],
)
```

That way, it's more clear what is inside of the tuple without actually looking through it.  I also like to have a trailing comma so that it isn't as easy to add another list and get a SyntaxError for forgetting it.

> ```
> def __init__(self, square=[]):
> ```

It is dangerous to use a mutable object as a default argument.  In this case it doesn't matter because you don't use it anyway.  As long as you aren't using it, you should use `None` instead.  That way, nothing needs to be created (`None` has already been defined, but an empty list needs to be created.)  When using `None`, use `if square is None:` instead of `if len(square) == 0:`.  While we're on that, you could have said `if not square:` instead of `if len(square) == 0:`

> ```
> self.squares = [None for i in range(9)]
> ```

Unused variables should be given the name `_` to make it clear that they are unused.  You don't even need a list comprehension here, though.  Just say `self.squares = [None] * 9`.  List comprehensions are useful in similar cases if the object is mutable and you want to instantiate a new one for each element in the list, but `None` is immutable so that is unnecessary in this case.

> ```
> if None not in [v for v in self.squares]:
> ```

Why create a list comprehension?  `self.squares` is already a list, so you can do `if None not in self.squares:`

> ```
> if self.winner() != None:
> ```

When comparing to `None`, you should usually use `is None` and `is not None`.  If you intend to compare with any Falsey value, you should be using `if self.winner():` instead.

That whole function can be combined into one line:

```
return None not in self.squares or self.winner() is not None:
```

> ```
> return self.complete() == True and self.winner() is None
> ```

You never need to say `== True` because if it is equal to `True`, it already has a boolean value.  Just say `return self.complete() and self.winner() is None`

> ```
> def winner(self, lastcheck = False):
> ```

From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements):

> Don't use spaces around the `=` sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value.

I strongly recommend that you read that whole PEP.

> ```
> if pos not in positions:
>     win = False
> ```

To save processing time, you should add `break`.

> ```
> return None
> ```

That is a completely useless line when given at the end of a function definition.  When no return statement is given, the function will return `None` by default.  Even if you were returning at an earlier time than the function would otherwise, you can say `return` without the `None`.  **Edit**: As Darkhogg has mentioned in the comments, it isn't *entirely* useless here.  It does improve the clarity of what happens when there is no winner.

> ```
> if len(board.available_moves()) == 9:
>     return 4
> ```

What are `9` and `4`?  This should at least have comments, but even better don't use hard-coded values.  Instead, define some constants at the beginning of the file.  That makes it easier to change your program later.

> ```
> def get_enemy(player):
>     if player == 'X':
>         return 'O'
>     return 'X'
> ```

This can be simplified to:

```
def get_enemy(player):
    return ('O', 'X')[player == 'X']
```

or:

```
def get_enemy(player):
    return 'O' if player == 'X' else 'X'
```

> ```
> a = sys.argv[1]
> ```

What if the user doesn't supply any arguments?  You'd have a very embarrassing error.  You should make sure that `sys.argv` has the right length before just taking right out of it.

> ```
> a = str.upper(a)
> ```

You don't need to call the class method with an instance as an argument; just use it like an instance method: `a = a.upper()`

> ```
> if v == '-':
> ```

Another hardcoded value.  Who knows? You may want to switch to using `*` later on.  Put a constant at the beginning of the file for your empty-space-filler and use that instead.

> ```
> if board.complete():
>     dat['Board']['Winner'] = board.winner()
>     dat['Board']['WinningCombo'] = board.lastwincombo;
>     ...
> ```

That code is in your program twice.  Duplicate code that is more than about three lines (in my opinion) should be in its own function.

Comment: Personally, I consider adding `return None` in a function that otherwise returns something good for clarity. Not adding it or using just `return` would be left for functions not intended to return anything.

Comment: @Darkhogg: You do have a good point there.  I think I'll edit.

Answer (score 8):

First, I would suggest simplifying your stack. You're running 3 languages for one simple app. Now given that the main bits of your app are the JS (UI) and Python (AI), you could drop the PHP. You can replace it with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), and simply import your AI like any other import.

```
onclick='ttt.ticclick(this)'
```

You use jQuery, yet you use inline scripts. I suggest using `$(selector).on('event', handler)` instead.

```
ttt = {
  "ticclick":
```

Naming could also need work. I don't really understand what `ttt` is if I didn't know the app was a tic-tac-toe game. I don't even know what `ticlick` is at all, even if I do know the game was tic-tac-toe.

```
jQuery.get("code/server.php?mode="+pre+"&data=" + ttt.system.boardencode(ttt.system.collect()), ttt.system.parseServerResponse);

// to

$.get('code/server.php', {
  mode: ...
  data: ...
}).then(function(response){
  // parse response
});
```

jQuery aliases the `jQuery` global with `$`. You can use that instead so it's shorter. Request data can be an object passed as the second argument of `$.get`. jQuery AJAX operations return a promise interface (fancy name for an object that holds state and has a `then` method). Use this, as it is more standard.

```
$('#spinner').css('width', '200px').css('height','200px');
```

Suggesting you move styling to a CSS class. Just let JS add/remove that class to apply/remove. That way, styling is easier to manage without diving into JS. Same goes for the rest.

```
console.log('Sending to server: ' + ttt.system.boardencode(ttt.system.collect()))
```

If the console calls are merely for debugging, I suggest you remove them and use the dev tools breakpoints instead. That way, leaving `console` calls won't be a habit. It's bad practice especially in real production code. It can break older browsers as well as increase the surface area for bugs. For instance, `ttt.system.collect()` returning something `ttt.system.boardencode()` never expected could break your app.

```
buffer[i] = $(ttt.realz[i]).html();
```

This is bad practice. Game state should be held in JS. HTML should merely be a representation of that state. When you render, you tell HTML to update based on that state, but that state remains in JS.

I also notice that you have an external stylesheet, yet still have styles in the HTML. I suggest you move that CSS out as well.

I'll leave it at that and let someone else do the Python.

Comment: One benefit of `console.log()` over breakpoints is that after something goes wrong, you can look back and see what the program thought it was trying to do.  Breakpoints can only show you what the program is trying to do *now*.

Comment: @Mark You do realize that you can set a breakpoint *and step through the code*.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer But never step *back* to see what happened *before*.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, can you set a breakpoint and step *backwards*, undoing the program execution?  I've never encountered a debugger that could do that.

Comment: @Mark Then you've never heard of [Historical Debugging](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/Marron/Time-Travel-Debugging-for-JavaScriptHTML). Besides, when you breakpoint, you have a stack trace. When you have a stack trace, you know where to put another breakpoint earlier in the stack and trace through forwards.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, is "historical debugging" actually *in* Edge, or is it yet another Microsoft Research project that never left the labs?  Looking at the stack trace is only useful if the bug is somewhere up the stack from you -- it's no good if it happened half an hour ago in a totally different branch of the program flow.

Answer (score 5):

### PHP

**Security**

Your code is quite insecure. If I call it as

```
?mode=foo&data=foo;id
```

the injected command will be executed. You would need to add `escapeshellarg` to make it secure.

**Misc**

- Bug: You are missing an `=`.
- Styling: All upper-case variables names are not all that nice to read.
- You are never using `mode`.

Comment: I understand this is a major security flaw. However this was not meant to be for online use, just for localhost and a science fair demonstration. I understand its good practice though.

Comment: @bytec0de This is indeed a gaping security hole. The only way to make this code remotely acceptable would be if you wrote a giant `# TODO: FIX ARBITRARY COMMAND EXECUTION VULNERABILITY` comment in the PHP script. It would really be better not to even write code this way in the first place. (Personally, I wouldn't even trust the PHP developers to have implemented `escapeshellarg()` correctly for all shells. I'd rather pipe the data to the child process.)

Answer (score 1):

TBH if you want a responsive interface in a browser (which will require JavaScript) and you have no need to access any real backend stuff like a database during the course of a game, you should just implement the whole thing in HTML and JavaScript. This is total overkill. At first I was thinking port that Python to the PHP layer but there's no need for the PHP layer, either.

Comment: I started out with HTML and then learned LAMP coding and lastly got into the advanced JS coding. I used to also have the same tendency to process everything in the backend but over time I realized that the only time you ever really need to contact the server other than initial page load is when you need to update or retrieve information from a database.